# Transportation and storage of atomic weapons

Tags: mechanical-engineering, experimental-physics, nuclear-engineering, nuclear-technology

I’ve been reading into the ministry of defence recently, and my question in general is this:

Considering that the UK and US have so many nuclear weapons, how do they:

1. store the nuclear weapons (isn’t it really dangerous to keep weapons of mass destruction packed together)
2. How do they transport them- surely you would need certain conditions to transport them. Maybe they take the weapon apart before transportation?

Comment: 1. why would they keep all of the weapons in one place? ... 2. think of a submarine

Comment: Hi, 1. I thought that they would store them in like one secure location? 2.but then how do they get from factory to submarine? And what conditions are safe for nuclear weapons in a submarine?

Comment: 1. why would anyone allow their weapon stockpile to be annihilated with a single strike?

Comment: Hi that makes sense. What about 2 please?

Comment: think about the stresses on the nuclear missile when it is launched ... do you honestly believe that it would be under greater stress on the back of a truck?

Comment: This might be of interest: [The delicate art of maintaining the United States' ageing nuclear weapons](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2023-09-24/the-delicate-art-of-maintaining-americas-ageing-nuclear-weapons/102893302).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general points:

Nuclear weapons cannot set each other off by virtue of the radioactive decay of their fissile components. So, for example, the warheads carried by ballistic missiles inside submarines are safely stored almost right next to one another in their silos. Note also that each warhead inside each silo actually consists of several separate nuclear bombs squeezed together inside one warhead housing- essentially "cheek to cheek"- with no risk of one irradiating the others into exploding. They are designed to prevent that from happening.

Next, note that both fission and fusion weapons contain a "pit" of (usually) plutonium which either constitutes the bomb itself (for a fission weapon) or the fuse that ignites the fusion reaction (for a fusion bomb). These pits are designed to be removable so that any time the bomb is in long-term storage or is being transported from one place to another the pit is removed beforehand and stored
or transported separately with tremendous care (see below). In this state, the pitless bomb isn't a bomb any longer.

There are extremely strict protocols and procedures for both storage and transport of both types of bombs (even with their pits out) and for the pits themselves.

I invite the experts here to correct and/or enlarge upon these points.